# Given finite subset of $\mathbb C[[X]]$, is there a ring automorphism of $\mathbb C[[X]]$, fixing $A$, but not fixing $\mathbb C$ set wise?

Tags: complex-analysis, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

For every  finite subset $A $ of $\mathbb C[[X]]$, does there exist a ring automorphism (bijective ring endomorphism ) $f$ of $\mathbb C[[X]]$ such that $f(a)=a, \forall a \in A$ but $f(\mathbb C) \ne \mathbb C$ ?

Related [Are $\mathbb C$ , $\mathbb C[X]$ definable in $\mathbb C[[X]]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2667763/are-mathbb-c-mathbb-cx-definable-in-mathbb-cx)  because if $D \subseteq M$ is definable by a set $A \subseteq M$  then $f(D)=D, \forall f \in Aut_A M$ , and in the related case we mean definable by some finite subset of $M$.

UPDATE : The partial answer by Alex Kruckman here [Given finite subset of $\mathbb C[[X]]$, does there exist a ring automorphism of $\mathbb C[[X]]$, fixing $A$, but not fixing $\mathbb C[X]$ set wise?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669359/given-finite-subset-of-mathbb-cx-does-there-exist-a-ring-automorphism-of) shows that these two questions are equivalent.

Comment: Related question: Is every algebraically closed subfield of $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$ contained in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman: That's a good question and unfortunately I don't know the answer ... but why is it relevant ?

Comment: Because if $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$ such that $f(\mathbb{C})\neq \mathbb{C}$, then either $f(\mathbb{C})$ or $f^{-1}(\mathbb{C})$ is an algebraically closed subfield which is not contained in $\mathbb{C}$. If no such subfield exists, no such automorphism exists.