# Is every algebraically closed subfield of $\mathbb C[[X]]$ contained in $\mathbb C$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, valuation-theory, formal-power-series

Let $F$ be a subring (with same unity) of $\mathbb C[[X]]$ such that $F$ is an algebraically closed field; then is it true that $F \subseteq \mathbb C$ ?

Since $F, \mathbb C$ are algebraically closed field of the same characteristic , so I know that either $F$ embeds in $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb C$ embeds in $F$ , but I am unable to say anything else.

Arose in a comment here [Given finite subset of $\mathbb C[[X]]$, is there a ring automorphism of $\mathbb C[[X]]$, fixing $A$, but not fixing $\mathbb C$ set wise?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2669549/given-finite-subset-of-mathbb-cx-is-there-a-ring-automorphism-of-mathb)

Comment: @egreg There are more invertible elements in $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$ than just constant power series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $a\in\mathbb{C}$ be any element that is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}$, let $b=a+X$, and consider the subfield $K=\mathbb{Q}(b)\subset\mathbb{C}[[X]]$ (any nontrivial polynomial in $b$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ has nonzero constant term and thus is invertible, so $b$ does generate a subfield of $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$).  Note that reduction mod $X$ map $\mathbb{C}[[X]]\to\mathbb{C}$ restricts to an isomorphism $K\to\mathbb{Q}(a)$ sending $b$ to $a$.  Now consider any irreducible polynomial $p(t)\in K[t]$.  When we reduce the coefficients of $p$ mod $X$, we get an irreducible polynomial $\tilde{p}(t)\in \mathbb{Q}(a)[t]$.  This irreducible polynomial has distinct roots in $\mathbb{C}$, and by Hensel's lemma each of these roots can be lifted to a root of $p(t)$ in $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$.

Now let $F$ be the algebraic closure of $K$ in $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$.  By the result of the previous paragraph, every irreducible polynomial over $K$ splits in $F$.  Since $F$ is algebraic over $K$, this means $F$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: Nice. And it seems like there's no problem with iterating this method transfinitely through a transcendence basis for $\mathbb{C}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, to obtain a subfield isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, right? Now I wonder if there's any chance that such an isomorphism extends to an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}[[X]]$...

Comment: Yeah, I think that works.  Or, rather than iterating, you could just start with an entire transcendence basis instead of just one transcendental element.